# java: rtsp stream to file using vlcj

Tags: java, file, rtsp, rtp, vlcj

I am trying to store a rtsp stream to file using vlcj.

I've done a couple of tutorials, looked at some of their test projects but haven't been able to do this.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Found an [An example of transcoding and saving video from a capture device.](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/capture/CaptureTest.java)  Trying to get it to work.  Looking for some documentation on the "options" part in `mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered me on the video lan forums, [check it out](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=107028).

My relevant code is below, where the most important part is the additional option for the vlc media player `":file{dst=C:/Users/the man/yahoo.mp4}"`.

```
    mFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    mPlayer = mFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

    String mrl = "rtsp://@" + addressStr + ":" + mPhoneRTSPPort;

    String options = ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=16},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}"
            + ":file{dst=C:/Users/the man/yahoo.mp4}";

    mPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
```

Comment: did you succeed to store streams from RTSP url in some media file ?

Comment: Yeah the above worked for me.  The only problem I had with vlcj was that if I had more than one instance running I would get random crashes, which apparently is a known issue.  I ended up using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) instead.

Comment: I want to play streaming from the following URL: rtsp://---.---.---.---:/archive/83145efb4c8091"
a
But I am getting the following error:
 live555 demux error: Failed to connect with (the above URL)
 core input error: open of (above URL) failed

Comment: And one more thing is this Streaming RTSP URL is password protected then how I can mention credentials ?

Comment: Sorry man, I haven't touched RTSP in over a year, so I'm not really sure how to help you.  Probably best to post your own question.